# Android: I want my dialogs to use the emulators default theme; how to call the setStyle() function

Tags: android, dialog

The problem is, the dialog's title background color is different in my emulator and on my real phone (each manufacturer uses it's own theme by default).

So I want to explicitly specify that I want to use the style that's using the emulator.

I'm guessing I can do it with

```
setStyle(style, theme)
```

inside DialogFragment but how can I find out which style/theme uses the emulator for building DialogFragments?

Answer (score 0):

in your manifest use default phone theme. `Theme.DeviceDefault`